# how can I uninstall using homebrew?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

Can I uninstall something I installed via homebrew using homebrew?

Answer (score 119):

You want to do:

```
brew uninstall program_name_here
```

Comment: I want to install something I installed using homebrew, not homebrew itself.

Comment: Changed answer per your comment.

Comment: @user27449: If this worked, mark it as accepted using the check mark button next to the answer.

Answer (score 21):

```
brew remove package_name_here

brew cleanup
```

Answer (score 3):

brew uninstall --force package_name